# "Illiberal" is not "not liberal"

Tags: word-usage

In a text I was reading about philosophy, there was the word *illiberal*. I guessed its meaning to be something like *not liberal* or *against liberalism*. But after checking the dictionary, I found out that it means *narrow-minded* which is really odd for me. Doesn't *liberal* stem from the French word *libre* meaning *freedom*? And isn't the initial letter *i* used for making something negative?

Update: What I'm asking here is not the meaning of these words, as they can be sought easily in a dictionary. Rather I'd like to see a morphological analysis of **liberal** and **illiberal**.

Comment: My dictionary says, "opposed to liberal principles; restricting freedom of thought or behavior." So... exactly what you thought it should mean.

Comment: Regarding your update:  The point of giving you the meanings was to show that, indeed, the morphological analysis is as simple as you initially thought.  Namely, the initial *i* is negating what follows.  Take *liberal* and negate it.  That covers *illiberal* quite nicely, and renders your subject line incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect *illiberal* meaning *narrow-minded* is the opposite of *liberal* meaning *free-thinking* or as in a *liberal arts education*.

Similarly *illiberal* meaning *mean* is the opposite of *liberal* meaning *generous*; and *illiberal* meaning *authoritarian* is the opposite of *liberal* meaning *supporting freedom*.

Comment: Dear @Henry, I appreciate your answer. But my question was kind of morphological analysis of **liberal** and **illiberal**. :). +1 for your help.

Comment: @Saeed: *illiberal* is *il- + liberal*, both from Latin where the *il-* is a version of *in-* meaning *not*.  [Wiktionary shows how *in-* in Latin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-#Particle) changed its spelling before other letters (compare *imbecile* with *inbound*).